# Return a variable from method in another class

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and trying to get my head around why the code below isn't working. I've tried to make a custom class HtmlRequest that isn't static so can be instantiated as many times as required using `HtmlRequest someVar = new HtmlRequest();`

return sb is holding the value but it's not being returned to `hmtmlString` on the line `htmlString = htmlReq.getHtml(uri)`.

I've tried putting Get{code ...return sb;} after public class HtmlRequest but can't get the correct syntax

```
   public partial class MainWindow : DXWindow
    {

            private void GetLinks()
            {
                HtmlRequest htmlReq = new HtmlRequest();
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/");
                StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();
                htmlString = htmlReq.getHtml(uri); //nothing returned on htmlString

            }

    }

    public class HtmlRequest
    {

        public StringBuilder getHtml(Uri uri)
        {
                // used to build entire input
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                // used on each read operation
                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

                // prepare the web page we will be asking for
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

                // execute the request
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                // we will read data via the response stream
                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                string tempString = null;
                int count = 0;

                Do
                {
                    // fill the buffer with data
                    count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    // make sure we read some data
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                        // continue building the string
                        sb.Append(tempString);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

                return sb;

        }

    }
```

If I put a breakpoint on `return sb;` then the variable is correct but is not returning it.
It's probably something really obvious, can someone explain why it's not working and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Try using the value instead of immediately exiting the method.  An optimized build won't save the return value if it isn't used.

Comment: i just tried this out and it works on this machine..?

Comment: @AustinSalonen - thanks that's it. I put a breakpoint on a temporary line `string pause;` and checked. If I actually use the variable then it has a value. That's a bit annoying! Is there any reason for this behaviour? If you add that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the value instead of immediately exiting the method.  An optimized build won't save the return value if it isn't used.

Comment: Thank you - I've now discovered one reason why it's better to start debugging in Debug configuration rather than Release!

Answer (score 1):

No need for this:

```
StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();
htmlString = htmlReq.getHtml(uri);
```

It's enough to say:

```
StringBuilder htmlString = htmlReq.getHtml(uri);
```

You'd have to define nothing. Nothing means "null", "garbage", what? Is htmlString the object it used to be? Or maybe the function does not return at all? What is it?

Comment: Thanks Marius - I did have your suggestion originally but changed it whilst debugging.